# Play Sound From ActionBar Button

Tags: java, android

Hi Guys I'm trying to play an audio file using an item on the `ActionBar`... I tried to put this but there is an error at the last  }); ... I wish you find a way to do that I always appreciate stack overflow members 'cause they help me. Thanks.

I tried this below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();



                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }

                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        });
```

Comment: i dont think that this will work..if u have a new code please support e with it,i cant acces my project now !!

Comment: Well, then post your LogCat later. It's going to be hard to know what's wrong with the information you provided.